# Passing a class type to a method, then casting to that type?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, casting

I'm still pretty new to Java, so I might be missing something obvious here.

I have the following code that I use to pick class types from a list of all my entities:

```
public Array<?> PickEntities(Class<?> cls) {
    Array<? super SpriteEntity> allEntities = new Array<Object>();
    for (SpriteEntity entity : MyGame.AllEntities) {
        if (entity.getClass() == cls) {
                allEntities.add(entity);
        }
    }
    return allEntities;
}
```

That works fine, but it means that when calling this method I still need to cast it to the class on the other side. For example:

```
asteroid = (Asteroid)PickEntities(Asteroid.class);
```

What I would like to do is use the class I am passing to my PickEntities class (the cls parameter) and then cast the returning array (allEntities) to *that* type.

Is there a way to do this? Whenever I try it just tells me that 'cls' is not a type and can't be used to cast.

Comment: Where is the class Array defined?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your method should be generic:

```
public <T extends SpriteEntity> List<T> pickEntities(Class<T> clazz) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (SpriteEntity entity : MyGame.allEntities) {
        if (entity.getClass() == clazz) {
            result.add((T) entity);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that I used standard collection classes, and standard Java naming conventions.

Comment: Wow, that's some awesome code! Works perfectly, and I got a lesson in how to better use Java  :D Thanks mate!

Comment: Note that the above code, like the code from the OP, will only include  instances where the class is exactly the same as `clazz`; it won't include subclasses. Also, you can avoid the cast by calling `clazz.cast(entity)`

Comment: If you want to include subclasses, you can use this code:
`if (clazz.isInstance(entity)) result.add(clazz.cast(entity));`